# Can I figure out a list of databases and the space used by SQL Server instances without writing SQL queries?

Tags: sql-server, wmi

I need to get a list of SQL server instances present on a computer, get a list of databases in each instance, and then determine how much space each database is taking up.

I can easily grab the instance names from the registry, but I don't have access to query the tables to get the names of the databases. Is there another way of doing this, maybe though WMI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging around, I finally found the WMI Class that will get my the info I need. On a server where I have 3 instances of SQL Server, I found my data in the following classes

```
Win32_PerfFormattedData_MSSQLINST2_MSSQLINST2Databases
Win32_PerfFormattedData_MSSQLINST3_MSSQLINST3Databases
Win32_PerfFormattedData_MSSQLSERVER_SQLServerDatabases
```

My instances are `MSSQLINST2`, `MSSQLINST3` and `MSSQLSERVER`. I couldn't figure out the naming scheme, so I had to look though all the classes to find out the information I needed. Anyway, here's the code that's working. Maybe someone will find it useful.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher sqlInstancesSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
    new ManagementScope(@"Root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement10"),
    new WqlObjectQuery("select * from SqlServiceAdvancedProperty where propertyindex = 12"),
    null);

foreach (ManagementObject instance in sqlInstancesSearcher.Get())
{
    string instanceName = instance["ServiceName"].ToString().Replace("$", String.Empty);
    Console.WriteLine("INSTANCE: " + instanceName);

    ManagementObjectSearcher classNameSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
        new ManagementScope(@"root\cimv2"),
        new WqlObjectQuery("select * from meta_class where __CLASS Like 'Win32_PerfFormattedData_" + instanceName + "%Databases%'"),
        null);

    foreach (ManagementClass wmiClass in classNameSearcher.Get())
    {
        string className = wmiClass["__CLASS"].ToString();
        string query = "select * from " + className;

        ManagementObjectSearcher databaseSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
            new ManagementScope(@"root\cimv2"),
            new WqlObjectQuery(query),
            null);

        foreach (ManagementObject database in databaseSearcher.Get())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  " + database["Name"]);
            Console.WriteLine("    Data Files     : " + database["DataFilesSizeKB"]);
            Console.WriteLine("    Log Files      : " + database["LogFilesSizeKB"]);
            Console.WriteLine("    Log Files Used : " + database["LogFilesSizeKB"]);
        }
    }
}
```